# Connect Laravel application on WSL2 with database on Windows

Tags: mysql, laravel, wsl-2

I have a laravel application using WSL2 that runs normally. I had a recent problem when I needed to connect this application with the database that is installed on Windows. I tried to connect several times and it always returns the following error:

```
sqLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I believe the problem is not with the credentials, as it is in the .env file below:

(the last 3 lines are confidential :D)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I'm using MySQL Workbench to access database data and it's working correctly. The same happens with the laravel application, which works correctly with the exception of this connection to this database in Windows. In other words, the applications work correctly, it seems that they are just not able to talk.

How do I make this Laravel application on WSL2 communicate with MySQL that was installed on Windows?

Comment: check the grant of the user if they extent to the database

Comment: the user has all privileges

Comment: Connection refused means the client could not connect to mysql server at all.

Comment: @DiChrist try this, instead of `127.0.0.1` try `localhost`.